# Are two 8dbi antennas equal to a 16dbi antenna gain? How much coverage will I get?

Tags: router, modem, antenna

I'm planning to buy a [TP-LINK TD-W8961ND](http://www.tp-link.com/us/products/details/cat-5512_TD-W8961ND.html) modem+router and two 8dBi TP-Link [TL-ANT2408CL](http://www.tp-link.com/us/products/details/TL-ANT2408CL.html) antennas. I'm going to attach the two 8dBi antennas into the modem, because this modem has two external connectors.

- How much coverage will I get for this configuration in meters (if the antennas have no interference)?
- Since I'm adding two 8dBi antennas will I get 16dBi antenna gain?

Comment: I would think that you'd want the minimum expected coverage for your situation. The maximum coverage tells you nothing useful; aside from how far someone could stand outside the door and hack it on a good day.

Comment: because my house is 3000 square feet so i want to know the signal strength of 8 dbi antenna

Comment: OK that means that if you look at the maximum coverage you'd only cover that distance on the very best days (or more likely not at all). If there is other interference, you'd have less coverage. I don't think anyone publishes that result though because it's all dependent on location, just like the answer to this question.

Comment: ok i want to know whelther will i get 16dbi antenna gain since i'm adding two 8 dbi antenna's???

Comment: No. It doesn't work that way. Use that calculator which was posted but I strongly doubt you have enough for full coverage of you location. You need to spread them out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These antennas you use are [omni-direction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omnidirectional_antenna), as described in the product link. Because of this, you may want to aim their tips into different directions to cover more space.

> Is 2 8dbi antenna's equal to 16dbi antenna gain?

No. Gain of two separate antennas does not add.

Answer (score 1):

TP-Link provides a handy calculator at [TP-Link Wireless Calculator](http://www.tp-link.com/en/support/calculator/):

The TP-LINK wireless calculator contains three different functions:

- Distance Calculation
- Link Budget Calculation
- Antenna Selection

Which function should you choose?

If you want to see the possible maximum separation of the transmitter and receiver while maintaining a certain link quality at different data transfer rates, you can choose the **distance calculation** function.

If you want to see the reliability of your wireless connection while the transmitter and receiver are working at a certain distance, you can choose the **link budget calculation** function.

If you want to find suitable transmitter and receiver antennas from our various antennas of which can meet the need of getting a good performance at a given distance, you can choose the function of **antenna selection**.

Look at the [Specifications](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/?model=TD-W8961ND#spec) for your router and feed in the data ...

Comment: Hello i tried tplink website not at all working

Comment: Works for me :/

Comment: It's not working here I just want to know how much coverage in meters will I get by adding two 8 dbi antenna if there are no interference